# How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL

Tags: mysql

In MySQL how do I define a custom sorting order.

To try to explain what I want consider this table:

```
ID  Language    Text
0   ENU         a
0   JPN         b
0   DAN         c       
1   ENU         d
1   JPN         e
1   DAN         f
2   etc...
```

here I want to return all rows sorted by Language and ascending ID so that Language = ENU comes first, then JPN and lastly DAN.

The result should be: a,d,b,e,c,f etc.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 360, accepted):

MySQL has a handy function called [`FIELD()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) which is excellent for tasks like this.

`ORDER BY FIELD(Language,'ENU','JPN','DAN'), ID`

Note however, that

1. It makes your SQL less portable, as other DBMSs might not have such function
2. When your list of languages (or other values to sort by) gets much longer, it's better to have a separate table with sortorder column for them, and join it to your queries for ordering.

Comment: Thanks this is perfectly for my situation where I just have to order by two values (a primary language, for example JPN, and a fallback language, for example ENU).

Comment: Man you just saved me a rewrite in magento :)

Comment: What if you have a `GROUP BY` before? For example, the first value i want, appears at the end?

Comment: Put the query with `GROUP BY` in a subquery, and order it in the outer query

Comment: Nice. I was writing a case order by clause, but field() is much more compact, and easier to reorder.

Comment: Works perfectly as of november 21, 2022!

Comment: Is there a way to make this work so that something not on the list is at the end, rather than the beginning? If I throw the example query 'RUS', it will put that *before* any of the ones specifically listed.

Answer (score 76):

If those are the only three values, then you can use [a `CASE` expression](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/control-flow-functions.html):

```
ORDER BY `ID`,
         CASE `Language`
         WHEN 'ENU' THEN 1
         WHEN 'JPN' THEN 2
         WHEN 'DAN' THEN 3
         END
```

(If there could be other values, then you may want to add some extra logic to keep the ordering consistent; for example, you might add `ELSE 4` to that `CASE` expression, and then order by `Language` itself as the third ordering criterion:

```
ORDER BY `ID`,
         CASE `Language`
         WHEN 'ENU' THEN 1
         WHEN 'JPN' THEN 2
         WHEN 'DAN' THEN 3
         ELSE 4
         END,
         `Language`
```

)

Comment: And if there are many Language values you could have a separate table storing each Language plus a sort order column and link to that

Comment: This will order by ID first, resulting in a,b,c,d,e,f

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly - as did Mchl answer which I accepted as it looks simpler

Answer (score 25):

You have a couple of options offhand,  the first is to change Language to be ENUM (assuming this is possible, and you only expect a few variations)

If you specify it as `ENUM('ENU','JPN','DAN')` then `ORDER Language ASC` will order in the order you specify.

The second will involve a case somewhere, i.e.

```
SELECT * FROM table
ORDER BY CASE Language
    WHEN 'ENU' THEN 3
    WHEN 'JPN' THEN 2
    WHEN 'DAN' THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END DESC, ID ASC
```

Performance-wise the ENUM method will return faster results, but be more hassle if you need to add more languages.   A third option would be to add a normalisation table for the Languages however that may be overkill in this instance.

Comment: Where exactly do you type `ENUM('ENU','JPN','DAN')`?

Comment: @pathros in the table definition, you specify it as an ENUM instead of VARCHAR etc.  Internally MySQL stores the ENUM options in a specific order and indexes them, and so when ordering by an ENUM column specifically it will use that internal index instead of the string values ( unless CAST() is used to make it back to a VARCHAR)

Comment: Shouldn't `END DESC,` be `END CASE  DESC,` ?

Comment: Nope.  Not all `CASE` need `END CASE`, it's dependant on context.  `CASE` within PROCEDURE require `END CASE` ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/case.html ) however `CASE` within SELECT does not require `END CASE`, simply `END` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case  ) - in this context it's a control flow function.

Answer (score 3):

For Yii2 framework we can achieve by following way

```
use yii\db\Expression;


Project::find()
->orderBy([
    new Expression('FIELD(pid_is_t_m,2,0,1)'),
    'task_last_work'=> SORT_ASC
])->all();
```

Comment: Your file should also have this line:
`use yii\db\Expression;`