# SQL order with Union

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, union

I want to select the union of the results from two queries.
What I'm trying to do is select one entry with a certain constraint, then add the remaining order by some other constraint.

I tried to do Union, but the order by on the second query fails, as it cannot order on a sub-query.

So what I did is declare a table variable, and then insert the single entry, then insert the rest of the entries order by constraint.

Is there a way to do this using union?

Comment: Can you post the queries?

Comment: What kind of database are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL Server, but I found the solution thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just wrap up the results of the queries that are unioned together and then perform the sort. Something like:

```
SELECT MainQ.* FROM 
(
  (SELECT * FROM MyTable AS T1 WHERE MyField = 1)
  UNION 
  (SELECT * FROM MyTable AS T2 WHERE MyField = 2)
) AS MainQ
ORDER BY MainQ.TableID
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the union statement as a subquery then select from it.

```
Select * from
(select fields,1 as orderby from table
 union all 
  select fields,2 from as orderby table)a
where whatever
order by orderby,whatever
```

The order by clause can also be heavily customized...  [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql)

for mysql for example.