# Move position of MySQL row up/down using php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli

I am fetching my page's menu from a MySQL table as an unordered list `<ul></ul>` ORDERERED BY their position, Here is my MySQL table's  screenshot
 
[image]

I want my query to work in a way like  when I fetch record of page_id_pk=3, it SET its page_position from 3 to 2 and updates it so now it holds page_position 2. The rest of the pages (rows) move down by an increment of one. **I don't want to just swap two rows but to change their position** i.e their page_id_pk sequence will remain same just their position gets changed.

Comment: What will happen if you change page_position 2 to 1 ?

Comment: Can you use something like set page_position=page_position+1 where page_position > the_position_you_set

Comment: You can use MYSQL's FIELD function in your order by clause [Custom Order By in MYSQL][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql

Comment: @DamienJoe I am afraid you don't quite understand the question.

Comment: @YourCommonSense I think he wants a custom order by?

Comment: @Serhat Akay I am fetching values ORDER BY page_position ASC so that matters the sequence of the menu

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Something like this for swapping

```sql
UPDATE `position_table` SET `page_position` = CASE  
                        WHEN (`page_position`=1)  THEN 2   
                        WHEN (`page_position`=2)  THEN 1
                        END 
WHERE `page_position` in (1, 2) -- last line to prevent whole table scan
```

And this for moving

```sql
-- old - old_position, new - new_position

UPDATE `position_table` SET
    `page_position` = CASE
        WHEN (`page_position` = old) THEN 
            new                                -- replace new within old
        WHEN (`page_position` > old and `page_position` <= new) THEN 
            `page_position`- 1                 -- moving up
        WHEN (`page_position` < old and `page_position` >= new) THEN 
            `page_position`+ 1                 -- moving down
        ELSE 
            `page_position`                    -- otherwise lets keep same value.
      END
```

Comment: @Faisal, just added some comments.

Comment: And when new position is small - lets say position was 1 set it 3, then?

Comment: Thank you so much you've been very supportive :)

Answer (score 0):

What will happen if you change page_position 2 to 1 ? If you can live with page_position number swap then do it that way...So page_position 3 to 2 is selected then make current 2 to 3
This way you can move them around one by one.
if 5 become 6 then old 6 becomes 5

Comment: I need to move them positions instead of swapping because when I have 100 pages if I want to move 100 on 1st then the 1st one will become 100th which I not what I want

Comment: That would be a rare case but still if you want to move 10th position to 5 then you will end up doing 5 swaps. 10<->9,9<->8,8<->7,7<->6,6<->5....If I were you thats what I would do. Moving 100th to 1st place might be a very rare.