# How to custom MySQL ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

Is it possible to write custom ORDER BY statement in MySQL

I mean, I have database like this,

```
id  time  day

1   1:55  Mon
2   2:00  Sun
3   1:00  Mon
4   3:00  Tue
5   2:30  Sun
```

I can write order statement like this,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY day
```

but is it possible to write query to get **Sun** as first and  **Tue** for second and **Mon** for third

This is wrong but like this query:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY Sun, Tue, Mon
```

Comment: did you see this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql

Answer (score 2):

Its possible

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY FIELD(day, Sun, Tue, Mon)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `day` is a `VARCHAR` you can write a lengthy `CASE WHEN` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM <table>
ORDER BY CASE day
    WHEN 'Sun' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Mon' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Tue' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Wed' THEN 4
    WHEN 'Thu' THEN 5
    WHEN 'Fri' THEN 6
    WHEN 'Sat' THEN 7
    ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 0):

The comment from arilia is the best way for mysql. For more portable sql try

```
order by day = 'sat', day = 'Fri'
```

And carry on for the rest of the days. That should work for all databases

Answer (score 0):

Try this [Check](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/209784)

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(day, Sun, Tue, Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri,Sat)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Custom order query of Mysql like below:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY FIELD(day, 'Sun', 'Tue', 'Mon')
```

For more information you can see the documentation :http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field