# how to sort mySQL results based on a string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a string of products I am requesting from a database like this:

```
$products_string = "706,714,713,715,716,717,720,753,754,781,782,785,710";
```

and then the mySQL query:

```
$select_products = $db->query("SELECT product_id, name FROM table_products 
WHERE product_id IN (".$products_string.") LIMIT 0,12");
```

I then present the products like this:

```
while($show_products = $db->fetch_array($select_products)){
    // products HTML here
}
```

The problem is, when they are returned they are sorted by product_id ascending, meaning they are returned like:

```
"706,710,713..." etc
```

When I want them returned in the same order as the `$products_string`.

Is there any simple way to achieve this?

Comment: nice answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql

Comment: Thank you so much! I searched and didn't find it! :)

Comment: google is cool, stackoverflow is awesome, the combination is how I get my job done ;-)