# Mysql order by OR sequence

Tags: mysql

I have MYSQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM  user WHERE name LIKE '%ana%' 
OR name LIKE '%adam%' 
OR name LIKE '%pit%'
```

Is any way to order result by OR sequence

I mean to display results with name `LIKE '%ana%'` as first 
name `LIKE '%adam%' as second` 
name `LIKE '%pit%' as third`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql)

Comment: i think you need to decide if it is A) =, or B) Like

Comment: I think the only think "like" is doing here is that it makes the comparison case insensitive.  Is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like

```
order by if(name like 'ana', 1, if(name like 'adam', 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 2):

First, use `IN` for the `where` clause (you don't have wildcards, so this is actually more efficient):

```
where name in ('ana', 'adam', 'pit')
```

Second, use `find_in_set()` for the ordering:

```
order by find_in_set(name, 'ana', 'adam', 'pit')
```

Comment: It's obviously more elegant, but is it actually more efficient too?

Comment: not much of a like :>   ... that said, i am upvoting, as it shows the community something !

Comment: It looks good, Can use this for modified query SELECT * FROM  user WHERE name LIKE '%ana%' 
OR name LIKE '%adam%' 
OR name LIKE '%pit%'

Comment: @Szmulik . . . No.  In that case, you would need an explicit `case` to order the rows (or perhaps use a secondary table).

Comment: @Strawberry . . . Yes, in general.  MySQL optimizes `in` with a list of constants by sorting the constants.  Okay, I admit that this probably has zero effect for three items, but in general, `IN` is more efficient than the equivalent `=` connected by `OR`. (And MySQL is the only database that I know of that does this optimization.)