# How to order and sort my records from eloquent

Tags: php, sorting, collections, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Hi I have a query which fetches all the category names and displays them in the frontend. now the problem is that category names have a field name called others ( it could be like other fruits or other vegetables etc). Now The others record names I want them to come in the last of the collection I get.

The query

```
$subcat = Category::where('parent_category_id', 62)->where('is_active', 1)->lists('name', 'id');
```

What It is gonna return is

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
    (
        [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [64] => Grapes
            [65] => Pineapple
            [66] => Cranberry
            [67] => Strawberry
            [68] => Pomogranate 
            [69] => Others //like this
            [71] => Orange & Apple
            [72] => Guava & Mango
            [73] => Mixed Fruit
            [384] => Other Juices //another one
            [395] => Concentrates
        )

    )
```

I want to place the other field names at the last.

Please assist me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql)

Comment: See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

Comment: It is sad that people have stopped going to the documentation and checking for the solutions (if it exists, already).. Downvote from me for not going through the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this is to add an `Sort_Order` column to your table, and then modify your existing query to be something like;

```
$subcat = Category::where('parent_category_id', 62)->where('is_active', 1)->orderBy('Sort_Order','desc')->lists('name', 'id');
```

This way you can explicitly set the sort order yourself in the database, without having to rely on the eloquent model to do any more than sort by the sort order you specified.