# sql query sorting year/month

Tags: mysql, sorting, sql-order-by

Hi my table structure is like this

```
year  month  name
2015   1     adc
2015   2     adc
2015   4     adc
2015   5     adc
2015   6     adc
2015   7     adc
2015   8     adc
2015   9     adc
2015   10    adc
2015   11    adc
2015   12    adc
2016   1     adc
2016   2     adc
2016   3     adc
```

I want to sort my query result always starting from month 4 of the year and end with month 3 of next year.for example if I want data of Year 2015 it should be like

```
    2015   4     adc
    2015   5     adc
    2015   6     adc
    2015   7     adc
    2015   8     adc
    2015   9     adc
    2015   10    adc
    2015   11    adc
    2015   12    adc
    2016   1     adc
    2016   2     adc
    2016   3     adc
```

can i do this with SQL query? here i need to increase the year also after month 12

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine multiple columns for a condition:

```
select *
from my_table t
where (year, month) >= (2015,   4)
  and (year, month) <= (2015+1, 3)
order by year, month
```

This one (in theory) should use the (year, month) index.

Answer (score 0):

solved it, thanks

```
select *
from my_table t
where (year=$year and month>=4)
  or(year=$year+1 and month<=3)
order by year, month
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11877629)

Comment: yes that is a complete answer, that actually is the solution

Comment: If possible, keep your code flexible for requirement changes. What will you do, if you want the entries from 04/2013 to 03/2016?

Comment: 04/2013 to 03/2016 yes this will not work but in my case the year increment is only by 1. I want to sort my query result starting from month 4 of the year and end with month 3 of next year @PaulSpiegel