# How to maintain a custom sort order in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database-design, database-schema

Say I have a dropdown buttons of credit cards.

My ordering is:

```
SELECT * from cards;

DISCOVER
MASTER-CARD
VISA
```

I actually want

```
MASTER-CARD
VISA
DISCOVER
```

**This is a custom order decided by business.**

So I though of maintaining a sequence_id in Mysql

```
DISCOVER 3
MASTER-CARD 1
VISA 2
```

So I can get these fields in order of their sequence_id.

```
SELECT * from cards order by sequence_id;

MASTER-CARD 1
VISA 2
DISCOVER 3
```

But the problem is when I have to add another card in the table, I will have to custom update all ids.
Is there a better way to maintain sequence?

[How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql) does not solve my problem as I can't specify all the fields in my query as the table is huge and keeps changing.

Comment: leave gaps use 10,20,30 etc new one can squeeze in between. This is why old line numbered programming languages always had line numbers in this fashion

Comment: Thanks I think this solves my problem. I can leave a gap of 50 or 100 for a lot of edits.

Answer (score 2):

The term `sequence_id` suggests that you want to use the primary key to keep order information. I see no benefit and lots of hassles in that approach. But it also suggest you don't have a primary key yet, which is not good either.

Just add a dedicated column:

```
CREATE TABLE cards (
   id int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   card_name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
   sort_order INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 9999999,

   PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

... and change your query to:

```
SELECT *
FROM cards
ORDER BY sort_order;
```

The 9999999 default is just a trick to ensure newly added cars show up last until you care sorting them—it's entirely optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(card, "MASTER-CARD,VISA,DISCOVER")
```

will sort with `card = 'MASTER-CARD'` first, etc.