# SQL PHP Sort Results WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a user database for a Clan. I am really inexperienced
with PHP and MySQL. The database selects users from a MySQL Table.
The users have a nickname and a user_status.

The first version I wrote ordered the Users as followed:

```
$sql = $sql . " ORDER BY user_status, nickname ASC";
```

So now the clan Leaders wish that the active Members show up first on that list. The problem with that is that there are user_status such as "abgelehnt" which means user refused in German.

And that's where the Trouble starts.
"abgelehnt" shows up higher than "aktiv".

I am really thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one

```
$sql = " SELECT filed1, field2, field3 FROM tablename
ORDER BY FIELD(status, "active", "inactive", "canceled")";
```

Change name of priority values according yours

Comment: Thank u so much. That was exactly the Reference I needed!