# Order the data as the IDs are ordered in the given list

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, wordpress

I'm running wordpress.

So have a comma separated string of post IDs and need to order found posts by the order which they are listed in the string.

Without sql query I can reach this simply by adding `'orderby' => 'post__in'` in arguments.

But I need to do it via sql query. Here is my SQL query:

```
$idList = '2,50,10,25,150,1200,356';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN ($idList)";
```

Above query return results in growing order, like this: `$idList = '2,10,25,50,150,356,1200';` but I need how they are ordered in my string. Didn't find how I can do the same in sql query. Any ideas please?

Comment: MySQL server or sql-server? MySQL has the FIELD function. you can try `SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN (2,50,10,25,150,1200,356) ORDER BY FIELD(ID, 2,50,10,25,150,1200,356)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL by using [FIELD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_field)

```
SELECT * FROM wp_posts WHERE ID IN ($idList) ORDER BY field(ID,$idList);
```

**EDIT :**

Check out this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9378709/5671807. I am quoting from

> Note however, that
>
> 1 - It makes your SQL less portable, as other DBMSs might not have such
>   function. 
>   2- When your list of languages (or other values to sort by) gets
>   much longer, it's better to have a separate table with sortorder
>   column for them, and join it to your queries for ordering.

Comment: I owe you a coffee :-P

Answer (score 0):

You can use `...ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID, $idList)`.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * 
 FROM wp_posts 
WHERE ID IN ($idList)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ID, $idList)
```

**Note:**

**FIND_IN_SET()** function

This function returns 0 when search string does not exist in the string list and returns NULL if either of the arguments is NULL.

**Syntax:**

```
FIND_IN_SET (search string, string list)
```