# Laravel Sort hasMany relationship by Array values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I have this method in a Model called Category, that brings all products from certain Category.

**Model:**

```php
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

What I would like is put these products in order based on Array with IDs.

I tried this but didn't work:

```php
public function products()
{
    if ( !is_null($this->products_order)) {
        $order = json_decode($this->products_order, true);

        $products = $this->hasMany(Product::class)->orderBy('id',...$order);
        return $products;
    }

    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

`$this->products_order` is a Array of IDs.

Comment: MySQL has a order by field, but other relational database don't afaik, so I wouldn't expect eloquent to support this since eloquent tries to be database agnostic.  If you don't case about coupling to mysql, you can look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql with a raw statement.

Comment: Instead of using column with arrays of ID, why dont you just create pivot table?

Comment: Thanks, guys. I changed my approach, I create a new field for product table called order, and I'ts work better.