# Flask SQLAlchemy - Default filter value if no results for provided filter

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask SQLAlchemy I'm querying a MySQL database with a table called `bar` and looking for rows that match a filter consisting of `foo` and `country_code`:

```
foo_filter = 'hello'
country_code_filter = 'ES'
result = Bar.filter_by(foo=foo_filter, country_code=country_code_filter).first()
```

The above code will return the first row in which `foo = foo_filter` and `country_code = country_code_filter`.

However, it's possible that we might not have rows for certain country codes that match `foo`. In these cases (i.e, cases where the above query returns 0 results), I'd like to use a default country filter of 'RoW' as our dataset should always have an RoW value for each possible value of `foo`. In the unexpected occurrence that this also doesn't return any results then an error should be thrown. This is the code I have for this:

```
foo_filter = 'hello'
country_code_filter = 'ES'
result = Bar.filter_by(foo=foo_filter, country_code=country_code_filter).first()
if not result:
    result = Bar.filter_by(foo=foo_filter, country_code='RoW').first()
if not result:
    raise RuntimeException(f"No data for combination {foo_filter}, {country_code_filter} or {foo_filter}, RoW")
```

This approach of running similar queries multiple times and checking the result each time until I get a row feels very messy/wrong but I haven't been able to find any better approaches that allow you to set an 'alternative' filter when your initial query returns 0 rows in Flask SQLAlchemy

Is there a cleaner approach to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution uses regular SQLAlchemy but running it on Flask-SQLAlchemy is just a couple of syntax changes away.

The idea is that we query for both the desired country code and the fall back one, ensure that the results are always sorted with the desired country code first and then limit the result to 1. E.g.:

```py
result = (
    s.query(Bar)
    .filter(
        Bar.foo == foo_filter,
        Bar.country_code.in_([country_code_filter, "RoW"]),
    )
    .order_by(func.FIELD(Bar.country_code, country_code_filter, "RoW"))
    .limit(1)
    .first()
)
```

The `FIELD` function in MySQL allows you to specify a custom sort order, in this case it ensures that if a result exists with the country code you want, it will always be returned first. You can read more about `FIELD` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql).

Here's the full test code:

```py
from sqlalchemy_app import Base, Session, engine  # you need to create these
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, func


class Bar(Base):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = Column(String(32))
    country_code = Column(String(32))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    s = Session()
    s.add_all(
        [
            Bar(foo="hello", country_code="ES"),
            Bar(foo="hello", country_code="ZIM"),
            Bar(foo="hello", country_code="RoW"),
        ]
    )
    s.commit()
    for foo_filter, country_code_filter, exp_res in (
        ("hello", "ES", "ES"),
        ("hello", "ZIM", "ZIM"),
        ("hello", "AUS", "RoW"),
        ("goodbye", "GBR", None),
    ):
        result = (
            s.query(Bar)
            .filter(
                Bar.foo == foo_filter,
                Bar.country_code.in_([country_code_filter, "RoW"]),
            )
            .order_by(func.FIELD(Bar.country_code, country_code_filter, "RoW"))
            .limit(1)
            .first()
        )
        assert getattr(result, "country_code", None) == exp_res
```

As you say that you want to raise an exception in the case that the query returns `None`, you can swap the `.first()` access method to `.one()` since the query limits the result set to 1 result server-side, you'll never hit the exception for returning more than 1 result and will raise a `NoResultFound` exception when no rows match the query.

Comment: This works really nicely and I appreciate the comprehensive test code. Thanks!