# Restaurant menu sorted by type of meal

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to sort a restaurant menu by type of meal. So appetizers first, main dish second, desert last.
When adding it to the database I use "soort" which gives it a type of meal.
When I run this code it wil show me the main dish, desert, appetizer which is the wrong order.
I can't figure out how to sort it the way I want it.

```
<?php
// vul de variable in die gebruikt worden om een connectie te maken (inlog gegevens)
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$naam = $soort = $prijs = $bijzonderheden = "";
$foutmelding1 = $foutmelding2 = $foutmelding3 = $foutmelding4 = "";

try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=restaurant", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} 
// connectie is mislukt
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}



?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
</body>
<table>

<tr> 
<th> Gerecht </th> <th> Soort </th> <th> Prijs </th> <th> Bijzonderheden </th> 
</tr>

<?php


$sth = $pdo->prepare('select * from gerechten ORDER BY Soort ');
$sth->execute();



while($row = $sth->fetch())
{
    
    
    echo "<tr> ";
        echo "<td>" . $row['Naam'] . "</td>"; 
        echo "<td>" . $row['Soort'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row['Prijs'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td> " . $row['Bijzonderheden'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr> "; 
    

}


// de update knoppen doorverwijzen met een href --> en dan een form maken voor 1 rij <-----------
?>

</table>

<style type="text/css">
    table {
        border-collapse: ;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 5px;
        
    }
    
    td  {
/*      border: 1px solid black;
        width: 25px; */
        text-align: center;
        padding: 15px;
    }
    </style>

</html>
```

This is the code that inserts the data in the database

```
<?php
// vul de variable in die gebruikt worden om een connectie te maken (inlog gegevens)
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$naam = $soort = $prijs = $bijzonderheden = "";
$foutmelding1 = $foutmelding2 = $foutmelding3 = $foutmelding4 = "";

try {
  $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=restaurant", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} 
// connectie is mislukt
catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}


// maakt een query 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    // begin waarde van de fout check variable
    $fout = FALSE;
// POST bijzonderheden mag hier wel blijven, want dat veld is niet verplicht om in te vullen.
    $bijzonderheden = $_POST['bijzonderheden'];
    // checkt of het veld 'naam' gevult is, zo niet dan geeft hij de melding vul het veld naam in
    if (!empty($_POST['naam'])) {
        $naam = $_POST['naam'];
    }
    else { $foutmelding1 = "vul het veld naam in";
        $fout = TRUE;
    }
    // checkt of het veld 'soort' gevult is, zo niet dan geeft hij de melding vul het veld naam in
    if (!empty($_POST['soort'])) {
        $soort = $_POST['soort'];
    }
    else { $foutmelding2 = "vul het veld soort in";
        $fout = TRUE;
    }
    // checkt of het veld 'prijs' gevult is, zo niet dan geeft hij de melding vul het veld naam in
    if (!empty($_POST['prijs'])) {
        $prijs = $_POST['prijs'];
    }
    else { $foutmelding3 = "vul het veld prijs in";
        $fout = TRUE;
    }
    // checkt of het veld 'bijzonderheden' gevult is, zo niet dan geeft hij de melding vul het veld naam in
//  if (!empty($_POST['bijzonderheden'])) {
//      $bijzonderheden = $_POST['bijzonderheden'];
//  }
//  else { $foutmelding4 = "vul het veld bijzonderheden in";
//      $fout = TRUE;
//  }

    if ($fout == FALSE)
    {

        // array aanmaken voor de parameters. 
        // Een array wordt gebruikt om de gegevens beveiligd te houden. 
        $parameters = array(':naam'=>$naam,
                    ':soort'=>$soort,
                    ':prijs'=>$prijs,
                    ':bijzonderheden'=>$bijzonderheden);

        // maakt een query die iets in de database gaat zetten
        $sth = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO gerechten ( Naam, Soort, Prijs, Bijzonderheden) VALUES (:naam, :soort, :prijs, :bijzonderheden)');
        $sth->execute($parameters);
        
        echo "toevoegen gelukt";
        
        header("Refresh:3");
    }
}
 
    
$sth = $pdo->prepare('select * from gerechten');
$sth->execute();

//while($row = $sth->fetch())
//{
//  echo  '<br />' . $row['Naam'].'<br />'.'<br />';
//}

?>




<html>  
<body>


 <h2>Gerecht toevoegen aan de database</h2>
<form action="" method="post">
Naam: <input type="text" name="naam" value="<?php echo $naam ?>"> <?php echo $foutmelding1; ?> <br> 
Soort: 
  <select id="soort" name="soort">
    <option value="voorgerecht" <?php if($soort == "voorgerecht") echo "selected" ?>>Voorgerecht</option>
    <option value="hoofdgerecht" <?php if($soort == "hoofdgerecht") echo "selected" ?>>Hoofdgerecht</option>
    <option value="nagerecht" <?php if($soort == "nagerecht") echo "selected" ?> >Nagerecht</option>
  </select> <?php echo $foutmelding2; ?><br>
Prijs <input type="number" min="1" step="any" " name="prijs" value="<?php echo $prijs ?>"> <?php echo $foutmelding3; ?><br>
Bijzonderheden <input type="text" name="bijzonderheden" value="<?php echo $bijzonderheden ?>"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="verzenden"><br>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there simply nozt enough information to help you, as long as you don't have the information about type in your menus (gerechten ) then there must be a joinable table that we don't know

Comment: I have added the page that adds the data to the database. Does this explain more ?

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all this non-sql stuff for now and just focus on the query (although I'm sure you could simply rearrange the array too)

Comment: `hoofdgerecht, nagerecht, voorgerecht` is the ascending alphabetical sort order, so the results are as expected. If you need a custom sorting order, please see [How to define a custom ORDER BY order in mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql).

Comment: in short you need an id in your table, which refers to another table with menytype which has only 3 columns id, text, orderby) and you join them and get your order by mealtgype, and also in which order the mealtypes should appear

Answer (score 0):

Needed to store the meal order in db first.

```
Table Meal
Meal(int id_autonumber PK, varchar mealType key, int mealOrder)
(1,appetiser,1)
(2,main dish,2) 
... etc
```

Then you get ordered by invoke sql = `select mealType from Meal order by mealOrder`

[image]

```
insert into wp_meal(mealType,mealOrder) values ('appetizer',1);
insert into wp_meal(mealType,mealOrder) values ('desert',3);
insert into wp_meal(mealType,mealOrder) values ('main dish',2);
```

Look at differences

[image]

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_meal` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `mealType` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci NOT NULL,
  `mealOrder` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
```

Comment: I think the column name has to come before the data type

Comment: @Strawberry  is not sql_create table, it's just a schema how to proceed

Comment: Well, it's only missing the words CREATE TABLE

Comment: @Strawberry Up to OP to write proper DDL

Comment: At this point, we don't know that they haven't

Comment: Sorry to be such a pain. I can't seem to figure it out. Its all to new for me.

Comment: you need to add also mealOrder in bd. Based on mealOrder , the client get the food properly (appetizers first_mealOrder_1, main dish second_mealOrder_2, desert last_mealOrder_3). This is what i was doing with `table Meal`

Comment: I see the image that you added. What are the PK, NN, UQ, B, UN, ZF, AI, G? I get the primary key one. If you wanne contact me in a other way i'm up for it btw.

Comment: better you take a tutorial of mySql, but i can provide the row sql. Also in order to be well structured MealType has to be key.

Comment: it's up to you how you create the table but the structure  should be the same ...

Comment: `mysql workbench` used for easy to do, but `create table` is independent of any tool (should have some similar `sql, except engine, charset`)