# Add New Result Below The Result of Mysql Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

This my table

[image: Table View]

This what I want

[image]

Its gonna be easy if we use php, but I want to know, is it possible with query?

Comment: Welcome! Stack Overflow is *not* a code writing service. We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. You are expected to try to write the code yourself. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is there a relationship between id and code ? Write an English description of your problem

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9378613/how-to-define-a-custom-order-by-order-in-mysql

Comment: @userMT Yes, There is a relationship between id and code, for example :
{id : 1, nama : tes, kode:111} have relationship to {id : 111, nama : tes, kode:0}

Comment: @RakeshJakhar we have different case

Comment: What have you researched? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: u need a better DB design. `id` is usually `auto-increment` in most DB design. What you need to do is make a separate table for the `kode` and `SELECT... JOIN` the tables

Comment: @zimorok I know that but, I just want know is it possible to do it in just one table?

Answer (score 0):

Select * from table where kode in (Select group_concat(id) as ids from table where kode=0)
Order by kode asc

you can try with this type of query