# Custom sorting in MySQL using FIELD, but put unknown/unexpected values at the end

Tags: mysql, sorting

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9378613/339440), someone asks how to do custom sorting in MySQL.  They give the following example dataset:

```
ID  Language    Text
0   ENU         a
0   JPN         b
0   DAN         c       
1   ENU         d
1   JPN         e
1   DAN         f
2   etc...
```

...for which they want results sorted non-alphabetically by Language, in the following order: ENU, JPN, DAN.

The accepted answer  says to use the MySQL `FIELD` command, like so:

`ORDER BY FIELD(Language,'ENU','JPN','DAN'), ID`

My question is this:  FIELD returns a numeric value by order, and sorts on that. So in the above, "ENU" is 1, "JPN" is 2, and "DAN" is 3.  If there is a value presented that is *not* explicitly listed in the FIELD function, it returns 0; which means the unspecified values will come *first* in the sorting.  Is there any way to have unexpected values sort *after* the custom-sorted values?  So if I'm sorting with that ORDER, and a record has a language of "RUS", that record would sort *last* instead of first?  If we have both "RUS" and "ESP", it would do the custom sort first, followed by the unexpected values alphabetically?

(I'm aware of CASE/WHEN, but FIELD is so much cleaner and compact, I was wondering if the same can be done in a similar manner to FIELD.)

Answer (score 1):

This is the one that puts unknown languages at the start:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY FIELD(Language,'ENU','JPN','DAN'), ID;
```

Here are two solutions that put the unknown languages at the end:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY FIELD(Language,'DAN','JPN','ENU') DESC, ID;

SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY 
  FIELD(Language,'ENU','JPN','DAN') = 0,
  FIELD(Language,'ENU','JPN','DAN'), ID;
```

[Dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/WkzMz_UV)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @bill-karwin
's answer, this works perfectly:

```sql
CREATE TABLE mytable (id int, language char(3), text text);  

INSERT INTO mytable VALUES 
  (0,'ENU','a'), 
  (0,'JPN','b'), 
  (0,'DAN','c'), 
  (1,'ENU','d'), 
  (1,'JPN','e'), 
  (1,'DAN','f'),
  (1,'RUS','g'),
  (1,'ESP','h');

SELECT * FROM mytable 
ORDER BY FIELD(Language, 'DAN', 'JPN', 'ENU') DESC, Language, ID;
```

The difference is this sorts the unexpected values alphabetically after the custom sorted values. Because FIELD returns 0 for all the unexpected values, it's easy to just add the second sort layer for the "zeroes".